# Selecting Top 10 with INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, indexing

I'm trying to produce a report that shows the top 10 users for each month and I'm a bit stuck on how to get it to work.

How I'd like it to work is I'd select from E1 the date and for the results to populate in E4 down.

I've tried using this formula

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$15,MATCH($E$1,$A$1:$A$15&LARGE($B$1:$B$15,D4)*1,2))
```

But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a basic version of my report.

[image: sample]

Comment: `LARGE` will not work with text values as you have in `$B$1:$B$15`. But the main question is: Top 10 users (colors?) in month in terms of what? In terms of count? How often they are listed in the month?

Comment: Hi Axel, the data i have is actually a list of companies and users that have called us in the past year, grouped by MMM-YY (Col A). I thought I'd just use colours to keep it simple. So each month it varies by who has called and the number of time they have called. The top 10 should list the 10 most frequent callers for that month. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have the top 10 of number of users in your list. I think the easiest solution is to use a Pivot Table. The steps to create such a table (I used Excel 2010):

- Go to *Insert* -> *Pivot Table*
- Set the *Report Filter* to Date, *Row Labels* to User, and *Values* to Count of User:
  [image: Pivot table]
- Then click on the button next to *Row Labels* in the excel and choose *Value Filters* -> *Top 10*. Then choose the Top 10 of the column you want (Count of User).
  [image: Select value filter.]
- Next, click again on the button next to *Row Lables* and click *More Sort Options...*.
- Then choose how you want to sort, I assume you want: Descending by Count of User.

Comment: Thanks for that agold. Ideally I'd like to use this as a formula if possible

Answer (score 0):

The pivot table solution is the best you can get in my opinion. But this is a good possibility for showing why pivot tables are so powerful.

For a formula solution I need three helper columns:

[image]

Formulas:

In `C2` and downwards:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)+MATCH(B2,B:B,0)/1000
```

In `D2` and downwards:

```
{=SUM(($A$1:$A$100=A2)*($C$1:$C$100>=C2)*(IFERROR(MATCH($C$1:$C$100,$C$1:$C$100,0),0)=ROW($C$1:$C$100)))}
```

This is an array formula. Put it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to complete.

In `E2` and downwards:

```
=A2+D2/1000
```

In `H4` and downwards:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($H$1+G4/1000,E:E,0))
```

Explanation:

The `COUNTIFS` is not as problematic in principle. But if different colors counts equal then surely they needs to be ranked different. So it becomes complicated the first time.

The ranking itself then is a mess with the multiple occurrences of the items and the condition. Only solution, I have found, is with an array formula which is of very bad performance.

For having a lookup column for the top ten then, I have added the date with the 1000th part of the rank.